# change the way my character moves, each time the character collides against the block

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

With this project I want to change the way my character moves i.e. each time the character collides against the block, rigidbody's isKinematic propriety becomes true and cannot re-receive damage for 3 seconds. When the time is up, change isKinematic to false and you can already receive damage again. Here are the lines of code for more details:

Comment: Changing 'isKinematic' is not the way here. 'isKinematic' means your player will not receive collisions from other kinematic objects, but it also means your player will pass through walls etc.

Comment: Why did you remove your code? Could you add it again?

Comment: And in general if there is any physics involved you do **not** want to apply anything via the `Transform` component in `Update! This completely breaks the physics and collision detection

Answer (score 0):

Changing 'isKinematic' is not the way here. 'isKinematic' means your player will not receive collisions from other kinematic objects, but it also means your player will pass through walls etc.

Instead, simply store `Time.time` in a variable every time you receive damage.

Now any time you want to check if the player is still invulnerable, check that more than 3 seconds has passed since the last collisions, by comparing 'Time.time' and the variable you stored.

If you really want your player to pass through any obstacle when they are invulnerable, you can use physics layers.